# How to replace placeholder to several lines using XWPFRun

Tags: java, ms-word, apache-poi

Right now I'm using XWPFRun to replace placeholders with some text. For example, read the ${topicName} placeholder from a Word document, and then from a property change it (for example, to: How to run a marathon?). But now I'm running into a problem where I have to replace the single ${runners} placeholder with a list of runners. Where the list will not be one line but one runner per line.

Now i use **run.setText(text, k);** to set text on run, so now i should find a way to set text on a run, but in several line

Comment: "to set text on a run, but in several line": Do using [XWPFRun.addBreak](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/xwpf/usermodel/XWPFRun.html#addBreak--) to add a line break into a `XWPFRun`.

Comment: thanks for answer, but in this scenario when, first i set some text on run, then addBreak, then again setText, the first text is replaced

Comment: i tried addCarriageReturn, but result is same